# Profile picture gets out of bounds

Tags: discussion, bug, design, profile-picture

Not a big issue, but it could annoy the OCDs among us.

Well, the image describe the bug (or it's not a bug?):

[image]

Comment: _[Insert comment about the drawings here]_

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. Shouldn't it be tagged as bug instead?

Comment: @FirstOne Like the fact the left one looks like a gramophone horn

Comment: @george Hey! That's Santa's hat.

Comment: @MarounMaroun ohhhhh, so it is, I can see that now!

Comment: How on Earth is that unclear?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I've no idea. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, The Free Hand Circle wasn't the correct line width - obviously. Also, you refused to fully color in Santa's hat.

Comment: I think how it isn't lined up [here](https://vimeo.com/189919038) correctly is more of an issue.