# Review Queue icon on Stack Overflow Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

I logged in this morning to the hat icon being added. But I also have this notification: [image: top bar]

However, I didn't think I had access to review queues on Meta which is true: [image: top bar with review menu open]

But why the notification? Clicking on it, or refreshing the page does not clear the icon.

I'm using: Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit). I also did not have this bug until this morning

EDIT:

This is also affecting StackOverflow's queues:[image]

Comment: Can confirm I see the same thing, same version of Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: Same on FF on MacOs

Comment: For those of us who *do* have access to the Meta review queues, the red dot doesn't go away.

Comment: Just reported on [OverMeta.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304437/im-seeing-red-dots-everywhere#304437)

Comment: @Chicken Three reasons. 1) I've been in the review queue on Main in the last hour, and still got the dot. 2) I have _never_ had the dot on Meta, as I cannot access any review queues on Meta. MattR would have the same. 3) See my previous comment, this appears to be network wide.

Comment: @Chicken, That *could* be a duplicate... but I did not have this problem until today. I've never seen this icon on Meta. My intuition leads me to believe that adding the hats icon could have messed with some things. Hats added today - "bug" happened today.

Comment: [Jon Chan has confirmed a fix is incoming.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304437/im-seeing-red-dots-everywhere#comment989580_304437)

Comment: Confirmed. Fix is going out.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier That is not a duplicate, this is confirmed a bug in the logic. That post is explaining the _intended_ logic.

Comment: @Kendra I was just pointing out : The issues concerning the red dot has been discussed many times, no offense.

Comment: Thanks for the fix @JonChan. On a side note, do we get a special hat for bringing this to community? I'd be happy to draw the hat free-hand... or we can use [this santa hat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360613/profile-picture-gets-out-of-bounds)?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Oh, I hope I didn't make you think I was upset, I'm sorry. I was only pointing out how it isn't a duplicate. My apologies if it came across as upset or aggressive!

Comment: @Kendra Not at all, i did not perceive anything aggressive don't worry, we explained our thoughts and understood each other's point of view, all's good :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed now. It was related to some changes we made to an upcoming feature we've been working on. Stay tuned!

Comment: can confirm the fix.